# List the full code of a knitr-type document at the end of the same document

Tags: r, knitr, sweave, r-markdown

````
One chunk silently generates output.

```{r, echo = FALSE}
summary(cars)
```

How can the same chunk be automatically listed at the end like this?

```
summary(cars)
```
````

`knitr::purl` with an argument `eval = FALSE` would work if it existed.

It would be ideal to list individual chunks by name.

Comment: are you looking for `eval =FALSE` option?

Comment: Yes, in that `purl` doesn't have one and I'm looking for something like it.  No in that `eval = FALSE` on a chunk would prevent it from generating any output.  `echo = "end_of_document"` is another way to think about it.

Comment: AFAIK purl doesn't evaluate the code, however I can't seem to avoid creating an output file, though the docs claim that the code should be returned as a character vector if output=NULL

Comment: @baptiste Are you sure?  The docs say `purl` is a wrapper to `knit` with `tangle = TRUE`, and I don't see anything in the `knit` source conditional on `tangle = TRUE` until after the code has been evaluated.

Comment: [Issue](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/934) raised regarding output=NULL, thanks baptiste.

Comment: you're right, for some reason I thought `purl` didn't run the code. That's unfortunate. I often use a different strategy, where my R code is in a separate R file, and I refer to those chunks with `read_chunk()`. With this workflow, it would be trivial to print the R file as text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have mentioned it in Section 12.1.4 of the first edition of the [knitr book](http://amzn.com/1482203537), which is basically:

````
```{r ref.label=knitr::all_labels()}
```
````

Comment: And a search for "reuse chunk" found it in your [online documentation](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/reference/) too.  I was missing the search lingo.